# Parameter Exception - was passed main parameter but no main parameter was defined in your arg class while launching Selenium Grid Node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

Error:

```
Parameter Exception - was passed main parameter but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
```

Snapshot of the error:

[image: Commandline output]

Hub - 10.72.24.148:5555

I am running node using command line:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.72.24.148:5555/grid/register -port 5566
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to launch the *Selenium Grid Node* is error prone. You need to drop the *double quotes* i.e. `"..."` around `C:\geckodriver.exe` and replace the single back slash i.e. `\` with escaped back slash i.e. `\\` as follows:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\\geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.72.24.148:5555/grid/register -port 5566
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please verify on what mistake am I making with this below command java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.130.106.33:4444/grid/register -port 5566

Comment: When I run this command I see the following message 
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-hub http://10.130.106.33:4444/grid/register -port' but no main parameter was defined in y
our arg class
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.initMainParameterValue(JCommander.java:936)

Comment: My colleague able to access my gird console using http://10.130.106.33:4444/grid/console using a browser. Could you please help me in understanding on what am I making.

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu Can you raise a new question with your new requirements please?

Comment: It would have been more helpful for me, if someobody has pointed out me that the "browser" name for Firefox was gecko, not firefox, here as well. I was fighting with -dWebdriver.firefox.driver= and not getting any visibility of the fault cause.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, above helps but also found in addition in Powershell, you have to use double quote, for example

```
java -"Dwebdriver.chrome.driver"=C:\Tools\chromedriver.exe  -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Above seems to work fine, note "Dwebdriver.chrome.driver"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed with this

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.185:4444/grid/register -maxSession 100 -browser browserName=”chrome”,version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=50
```